# How to avoid conflict of namespaces that end in the same word in typescript

Tags: typescript, dynamics-crm

I have code generated namespace

```
declare namespace Form.crg_contract.Main { ...auto generated code... }
```

I have a my own namespace where I reference the one above, but it keeps thinking is self referencing so it cant see from.crg_contract

```
    namespace CRG.Contact.Form { 
declare var Xrm: Xrm<Form.crg_contract.Main.Information>;
        }
```

thoughts???

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can't access global entity with the same name.

Correspoding TypeScript issue was rejected a while ago: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983

Motivation: "You're fundamentally out of luck because JavaScript has lexical scoping. There's nothing TypeScript can do to let you access an outer thing of the same name."

You can come up with some aliasing like below, if this makes sense in your project structure. Or just change the names a little.

```
namespace Form.crg_contract.Main { 
    export class Information {
    }
}

namespace Local {
  export import Main = Form.crg_contract.Main;
}

namespace CRG.Contact.Form { 
    var test: Local.Main.Information;
}
```